# Проверка параллельной авторизации в Magento 2

Tags: magento

Я пытаюсь проверить в фронтэнде Magento 2 авторизован ли параллельно администратор, но у меня не получается. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и может подсказать решение?

Пример моего кода:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var Http $request */
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $isEnabled = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
        ->getValue('maintenance_mode/maintenance_mode_settings/enabled');
    if ($isEnabled == 1) {
        $page = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
            ->getValue('maintenance_mode/maintenance_mode_settings/page');
        if (  ...  ) {
            return false;
        }
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect('/' . $page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: я новенький в magento  и требуется создать модуль (свой observer метод). В блоке  if (...)  идет проверка если админ авторизован значит он будет иметь доступ ко всем страницам, иначе срабатывает редирект.

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko, а почему параллельной?